# How do I conditionally highlight cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

Not sure if I'm sharing this right but below is a link to my sheet. Cell C3 is past today so it is red. What I'm trying to do is have it go back to white when I enter the next "Last change" date in cell A4 and continue in this manner. This possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(C3 < TODAY(), C3<>"", A4=""), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: @Tim done. check your sheet. I used `=IF(AND(C3 < TODAY(), C3<>"", A4="", C3<>0), 1)`. also if you dont want SUM to show 0 when there are no data to sum, use: `=if(B3<>"",sum(A3,B3),)`

Comment: Thanks!! You are awesome!! I also found if I change your =if(B3<>..... to =if(A3<>...... it eliminates the "0's" and works great. Thanks again!!